# Why can't I use _Generic in C++ code?

Tags: c++

I find that to instantiate a _Generic, the source file needs to be a .c file and compiled with gcc -std=c11. Naming it as a .cpp file and using g++ -std=c++11 does not work. Neither does g++ -std=c11 (which is expected because the -std=c11 switch is only applicable for .c files). What is a good way to define _Generic functions in a C++ library, and let a C++ application use the library? The intent is to support C applications but without abandoning support for C++ applications.

Comment: Because C and C++ are **different** languages, governed by **different** standards that are composed by **different** committees.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no `_Generic` in C++ and you cannot use it in C++ code. If you want to design cross-compilable code (e.g. header files), either avoid `_Generic` entirely, or use `#ifdef __cplusplus` to provide two independent (or semi-independent) versions of the same code for C and C++ separately, e.g. use function overloading on C++ side instead of `_Generic`.

Comment: What other C features aren't present in C++? C++20 added a major one, designated initialisers.